# loadUrl() crashes with CordovaWebView

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I know that there are some posts here but they are not solving my problem.
The thing is:

I have a Cordova App (android platform). In my activity_main.xml I have declared a CordovaWebView and I want to call loadUrl() method to load a website that is in my assets folder. When I invoke the method the app crashes showing "UNFORTUNATELY, MyApp HAS STOPPED".

**STRANGE THINGS I HAVE NOTICED:**

- If I emulate using a device with API 10 or 16, this **WORKS FINE**. If I test it with 17 it does **NOT WORK**.
- If I don't use CordovaWebView and directly invoke: `this.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");` it works fine, but it's like I am not using the layouts I define (so I don't have my ad banner).

Any ideas about this problem??

Thanks!

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
   android:id="@+id/layout_home"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_banner"
            android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal">

            <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
                    android:id="@+id/webview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled" />
       </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/wallet_hint_foreground_holo_dark">
       </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainAcitivy.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {

CordovaWebView cwv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ..LOAD ADVERTISEMENT INTO LAYOUT_BANNER... 

    cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    cwv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need activity_main.xml and all android stuff, just start a fresh project using cordova command line. You don't need any xml of that sort in standard cordova project.

Comment: @mentat, if I do what you say, how do I add the Advertisement banner at the bottom?

Comment: I don't know what you use as banner but in theory you can just put it in a div in your html I suppose.

Comment: @mentat yes, I thought about that, but I wanted to insert my Ad in a layout. The banner I use is a layout where I insert an AdView and that is loaded with an Ad from GooglePlayServices (AdMob).

Comment: You've got cordova plugins for that http://plugreg.com/search?q=admob By the way I deserve an accepted answer :)

Comment: @mentat Great! I did that and now is working. Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you need activity_main.xml and all android stuff, just start a fresh project using cordova command line. You don't need any xml of that sort in standard cordova project.

You've got cordova plugins for displaying admob ads inside cordova web view, see http://plugreg.com/search?q=admob

Answer (score 0):

look the doc : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html

```
cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.cordovaview);
Config.init(this);
cwv.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
```

you can see a sample here : https://github.com/dam1/sample-android-cordova-webview